# Convert row record to column for each emp using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have a table `tb_phone` with

```
person_number    home_number   mobile_number work_number
1                34646         989938377      9800
2                 83837        981083737      890
3                 64746        982726666      8373
```

i the phone_type be 'W' if work_number is there and 'M' if mobile number is not null and 'H' if home is not null

```
person_number    PHONE_number   phone_type
 1                  34646         H
 1                  989938377     M
 1                  9800          W
 2                  83837         H
 2                  981083737     M
 2                  890           W
```

Is this possible through any query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `UNION ALL`, with one select for each number type:

```
select person_number, home_number as PHONE_number, 'H' from tb_phone
UNION ALL
select person_number, mobile_number, 'M' from tb_phone
UNION ALL
select person_number, work_number,   'W' from tb_phone
```

Perhaps you want to add `WHERE xyz_number is not null` to each select to avoid null numbers?

Comment: Oracle is fine with the `as` before the column alias.  It doesn't accept `as` before table aliases.

Comment: Thanks, removed that part.